# Start Scene without clicking start button on amazon sumerian

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sumerian

I am beginner in AWS Sumerian, I want to start scene without clicking start button.
as shown in the image.

[image]

please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: When are you getting the start button?
Usually when you publish you just get the URL, which is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an initial state in your state diagram, which may be the same as what is run when you press the start button. However if your start button runs certain scripts like speech, you may need to begin with an AWS SDK ready action, then transition.

Since I don't know your project, here is a sample tutorial from Amazon that you can walk through to see how it works: [Sumerian Speech tutorial, will speak when run using initial state](https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/beginner/speech-component/)

And here are more: [Sumerian Tutorials](https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/)